# Convolutional Neural Network - Not showing total number of train samples

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, epoch

My x_train is a numpy array with 639 elements.

Upon running model.fit(), why does it show the following:

```
Epoch 1/50
20/20
```

It shows 20/20 instead of 639/639.

Comment: It shows the number of batches, not samples. Presumably are using the default batch size of 32 which would fit perfectly.

Comment: oh i see thanks!